# regular expression to reverse text order

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace, reverse

I need to reverse the order of an html files title tag..  so the first text before the : are put at the end, and so on

original:

```
<title>text: texttwo: three more: four | site.com</title>
```

output:

```
<title>four: three more: texttwo: text | site.com</title>
```

the title inside is divided by :  and needed to reverse the order, sometimes they are four (separated with three : and sometimes they are three, or whatever..

I use Notepad++ to replace.. - or if you want to suggest any other easy software to use to do that..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that this can be done with a standard regular expression - at least not with the requirement of needing to support any number of fields.

Assuming you have a large number of these to process, I'd use your favorite programming or scripting language, split the fields into an array (you can use regular expressions for this) - then read back from the array in reverse.

Comment: is there any other alternatives of software that I could use to do that? as I am not familiar with scripting languages and programming..

Comment: @Mike - what is your use case here?  Do you have many of these?  If so, do you already have all the inputs available in a single file?  Or do you need to search for and read the line from saved files, etc.?

Comment: in np++ for example I could open all the files, and search and replace in all the open files at once..  I think other software can do that too..

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to write code (which I think is not a good idea because it is a really good opportunity to learn something new) you can try this:

http://jsimlo.sk/notepad/manual/wiki/index.php/Reverse_tools (Order of Words on Each Line (Ctrl+Shift+F))

but you need to download this:

http://jsimlo.sk/notepad/

Comment: thanks John, however, it won't work, as there are many words before and after each :  so the point is taking whatever before the : and put them at the end, and so on..  not word by word

Comment: ok. so you should try to write code, for instance in php, Java, C# (IO are very easy to manipulate), some example: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=589260